# Azure ML Studio Designer - Is it possible to copy pipeline or pipeline drafts from one workspace to another?

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk, azuremlsdk

Is it possible to export or copy Pipelines created in Azure ML Studio *Designer* from one Workspace to another, using the UI, python sdk, and/or azure CLI?  If so, how?

EDIT:  My Designer does not appear to have the 'Export To Code' option that DeepDave-MT shows below.  How do I enable this ability?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This export Designer pipeline to code feature is only available in 1P subscriptions. Currently not exposed this feature because the py code exported are based on a internal version of SDK which mainly support 1P customers . The code there will most likely be changed when we preview SDK 2.0 with 3P customer.

At the meanwhile, we heard a lot feedbacks about the importance for export/import feature as 3P customers want to leverage this feature to move their pipeline from 1 workspace to another or archive their pipeline to code to integrate with Github etc. most likely will private preview the “export pipeline to Yaml” with DevPlat V2 private preview.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  What is a 1P vs 3P subscription/customer?  Do you have any idea when the SDK 2.0 preview will be available to 3P customers?

Comment: Is there any update on this? If the export or source control integration isn't currently possible for Azure ML designer pipelines, then they cannot be deployed to other environments with MLOps? Can someone please confirm?